# Can't figure out why I'm getting a Run-Time Error 9: Subscript Out of Range Error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that is run during the Workbook_BeforeSave event, which is intended to save part of the spreadsheet to an external text file, that is used for syncing data between several workbooks.

The code is as follows:

```
Sub SaveSyncFile()

    Dim syncfilename As String, lineText As String
    Dim myrng As Range, i, j

    syncfilename = "\\fs01\G_Share\a account information\Account Functions & Tools\Menus\Account Recipes\" & Worksheets("DevTools").Range("D2").Value & " recipes.txt"

    Open syncfilename For Output As #1

    Set myrng = Range("AcctRec")

    For i = 1 To myrng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To myrng.Columns.Count
            lineText = IIf(j = 1, "", lineText & ",") & myrng.Cells(i, j)
        Next j
        Print #1, lineText
    Next i

    Close #1

End Sub
```

When the file is closing *sometimes*, this line is where the error occurs:
`syncfilename = "\\fs01\G_Share\a account information\Account Functions & Tools\Menus\Account Recipes\" & Worksheets("DevTools").Range("D2").Value & " recipes.txt"`

So, when I debug, I can get the results of `?"\\fs01\G_Share\a account information\Account Functions & Tools\Menus\Account Recipes\" & Worksheets("DevTools").Range("D2").Value & " recipes.txt"` in the immediate window, but if I try to get `?syncfilename`, it shows no value...

So, it seems like there is something to the assignment of the variable's value?

Also, more info... this Sub seems to work without error if simply running the Sub directly... but when the sub is called from the Workbook_BeforeSave event, the error sometimes occurs.

Any idea how to resolve?

Comment: If that code is in the same workbook as the DevTools sheet, use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DevTools").Range("D2").Value` rather than just `Worksheets("DevTools").Range("D2").Value`

Comment: Unfortunately, the code is in an add-in that I've created.  I also tried using `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DevTools").Range("D2").Value`, and got the same error

Comment: The error suggests that whatever workbook is active at the time does not have a sheet by that name. It seems like a very odd setup to me for code in an add-in to assume that another workbook has a specific sheet in it.

Comment: The add-in is basically a repository of all the code necessary to run the functions of the spreadsheet -- it only runs when the particular spreadsheet is open.  There are literally dozens of these spreadsheets, all set up the same way with the same tabs, only differing dates/account names/data.  To update any code, I only need to change code in the add-in, and it will be applied to all of these spreadsheets.

So, it sounds like, per your description, there might be a "focus" issue, in that the "code" thinks that the add-in might be the activeworkbook, not the spreadsheet itself.

Comment: so, adding `debug.print ActiveWorkbook.Name` line just before the error occurs does in fact confirm that the code is looking to find the Sheet and Cell for the add-in file, and not the spreadsheet calling the sub.  I'll need to figure out how to specifically refer to the spreadsheet, or I might pass the value in as a variable before calling that sub... either way, THANK YOU for the suggestion to go down that route!